# How add headers in HttpRequestHeaders and WebHeaderCollection in Generic method?

Tags: c#, http, header

**Hello!**

I have method "AddHeaders()":

```
public void AddHeaders(object collection)
{
collection.Add("key1", 111);
collection.Add("key2", 222);
collection.Add("key3", 333);
...
}
```

But this collection has types: 
`HttpRequestHeaders` and `WebHeaderCollection`

**How can i write generic method to to this ?**

Comment: add two overloads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void AddHeaders(T collection) Where T is HttpRequestHeaders
{
collection.Add("key1", 111);
collection.Add("key2", 222);
collection.Add("key3", 333); 
}

public void AddHeaders(T collection) Where T is WebHeaderCollection
{
collection.Add("key1", 111);
collection.Add("key2", 222);
collection.Add("key3", 333); 
}
```

Just try to combine these two to one.